# How to shade a region in Google Maps with Zip Code

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can I shade a region in Google Maps by providing a zipcode? I have a JSON data of 44 zipcodes. I have the UI with list of those zipcode. I basically want to shade a region with those zipcode when I click the single list. Render one shaded region at a time. I am using Angular and HTML.

eg:

```
No.    Zipcode
--------------
1       334422
2       233241
3       545322
4       653452
5       984393
.... more datas
```

Comment: you need to know the bounds of those zipcodes

Comment: @charlietfl - How do I know the bounds? or if I could use Google Maps API to get those bounds...